# Why toString does not work when String.valueOf() works at casting

Tags: java, scala, casting, autoboxing

I need to parse Json into Map[String,String] structure. Json may contain numeric and string types as values.

So in order to store it as String I've applied toString method and it throws ClassCastException. However if String.valueOf() is applied everything is OK.

1. Why so?
2. If there are better way to do such casting?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

import scala.collection.Map
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)


val str = "[ { \"name\": \"VehicleType\", \"value\": 11 }, { \"name\": \"VehicleWeight\", \"value\": \"12000\" } ]"
val customfields = JSON.parseFull(str) match {
  case Some(map: List[Map[String, String]]) =>
    // map.map(map => {map("name") -> map("value").toString}).toMap

    // that throws:
    // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    //  at #worksheet#.$anonfun$customfields$1.apply(scratch.scala2:14)
    //  at #worksheet#.$anonfun$customfields$1.apply(scratch.scala2:14)
    //  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(scratch.scala2:269)
    //  at #worksheet#.customfields$lzycompute(scratch.scala2:14)

    // that works fine 
    map.map(map => {map("name") -> String.valueOf(map("value"))}).toMap
  case _ => Map.empty[String, String]
}
```

Comment: I believe what's happened here is: The first `match` case casts the parse result to `List[Map[String, String]]` even though that's not what it is; due to partial type erasure, the cast of the `List` does not fail. At that point, what you've got is *heap pollution*: there are `Double` values with a static type of `String`, resulting in a `ClassCastException` when you attempt to dereference one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the pattern matching match the List type, but doesn't go all the way to all types inside the map, that's why you enter the `Some` clause.

So, instead of the 
  `case Some(map: List[Map[String, String]]) =>`

Try do this:

```
case Some(map: List[Map[String, _]]) =>
     map.map(map => {map("name") -> 
     map("value") match {
     case s: String => s
     case i: java.lang.Number => i
     case unexpectedType => throw Exception(s"Unexpected type $unexpectedType")
   }.toString}).toMap
```

That's how you can handle every value in your map safely.